# Change the text of the clicked button

Tags: jquery

I need a way to toggle the text inside (this) though this code i have doesn't do it right and i cant get why. The text to be toggled is inside the show class.

```
  $('.show').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('.less').next('.more').toggle(function (){
        $(this).text("change text")
        .stop();
    }, function(){
        $(this).text("change text again")
        .stop();
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you the markup that goes with it or jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the `toggle()` function was deprecated and removed :

```
$('.show').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text(function(_,txt){
        return txt == 'show' ? 'hide' : 'show';
    }).closest('.less').next('.more').toggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nAdSU/)

Comment: Thank you, the website is only to be used until september so it's fine for now.